# NSURL URLWithString to a relative url

Tags: ios, django, api, upload

I want to upload a image(UIImage) from ios app to django website.(where has forms and submit button, just like normal web page.)

So I decide to use ASIFormDataRequest for that. (I'm a noob, am I doing right?)

First,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someec2site/profile/album/2/upload/"];
```

Error: The current URL, `profile/album/2/upload/`, didn't match any of these.

So, I did,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someec2site/profile/albums/(?P&lt;album_id&gt;\d+)/upload/"];
```

ERROR: Unknown escape sequence '\d'

I have a question.

1) Am I doing right?

2) How can I grab a relative url for string? (redirecting urls based on url.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Your choice of using ASI is very good for HTTP requests.

If I am not mistaken you are trying to construct the upload urls for different album ids.

Why don't you try this:

```
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someec2site/profile/album/%d/upload/",albumId];
NSURL * url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: But albumID part is confusing. I'm like <int albumId = 2>(it's 2 according to browser, so for now, for testing, I gave it 2.) But debugger says "didn't match! Anyway, thanks for the tip helps much!

Comment: wow, it's working. It was .../albums, not .../album. Thank you very much!